# Better socket communication system

Tags: vb.net, sockets

Currently, the client is sending messages like this:

```
Public Function checkMD5(ByVal userID As Integer, ByVal gameID As Integer, ByVal file As String, ByVal fileFull As String) As String
    Dim make As New CMakeMSG
    Dim md5 As New CMD5
    make.append("checkfileMD5")
    make.append(userID)
    make.append(containerID)
    make.append(file)
    make.append(md5.GenerateFileHash(fileFull))

    Return SocketSendAndReceiveMSG(make.makestring)
End Function
```

The server may receive something like this:

`checkfileMD5-MSGDelimit0-12-MSGDelimit1-54-MSGDelimit2-filename.txt-MSGDelimit3-*md5hash*`

Which it then reads out:

```
Private _message As String
Public Function handleMessage() As String
    Dim brokenMessage As New ArrayList
    brokenMessage = breakDown() 'Split to ArrayList

        If brokenMessage(0) = "checkfileMD5" Then
            Try
                If brokenMessage.Count > 5 Then
                    Return "0-structureMessedUp"
                End If
                Return CompareFileMD5(brokenMessage(1), brokenMessage(2), brokenMessage(3), brokenMessage(4))
            Catch ex As Exception
                Return "0-structureMessedUp"
            End Try
        End If
End Function
```

So what it does is take the received message, and split it to an array using the -MSGDelimit- as a delimiter. So in this case the `CompareFileMD5()` function would receive `12,54,filename.txt,*md5hash*`. And based on that it can return to the client whether or not the MD5 matched.

Sure, it works, but it feels sloppy and code on the server gets really messy.

Here's the less relevant functions from the above code (doubt it matters, but you never know):

```
Private Function breakDown() As ArrayList
    Try
        Dim theArray As New ArrayList
        Dim copymsg As String = _message

        Dim counter As Integer = 0
        Do Until Not copymsg.Contains("-MSGDelimit")
            Dim found As String

            found = copymsg.Substring(0, copymsg.IndexOf("-MSGDelimit" & counter & "-"))

            theArray.Add(found)
            copymsg = copymsg.Replace(found & "-MSGDelimit" & counter & "-", "")

            counter += 1
        Loop

        theArray.Add(copymsg)
        Return theArray
    Catch ex As Exception
        Module1.msg(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Function

Private Function CompareFileMD5(ByVal userID As Integer, ByVal gameID As Integer, ByVal filename As String, ByVal source As String) As String
    Try
        Dim tryFindFile As String = Module1.filedatabase.findfile(userID, gameID, filename)

        If Not tryFindFile = "notFound" Then
            Dim fileFull As String = tryFindFile & "\" & filename
            Dim md5 As New CMD5
            If md5.GenerateFileHash(fileFull) = source Then
                Return "Match"
            Else
                Return "NoMatch"
            End If
        Else
            Return "notFound"
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Module1.msg("0")
        Return "0"
    End Try
End Function
```

So, any advice on how to handle it better/cleaner/more professional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the application, your current solution may be perfectly fine.  There are a couple of things that do stand out a little bit:

- The "protocol" is a bit heavy in terms of the amount of data sent.  The delimiters between the data pieces adds quite a bit of overhead. In the example, it makes up maybe 50% of the payload.  In addition, sending all data as text potentially makes the payload larger than absolutely necessary.  All of this, though, is not necessarily a problem.  If the traffic between the client and server is relatively light, then the extra data on the wire may not be a problem at all.  For a request of this size (with or without the relatively high delimiter overhead), the main cost will be round trip costs and would likely change very little by reducing the size of this packet by half.  If, though, there are requests with thousands of pieces of data, then reducing the payload size would help.
- The use of the delimiters as shown is potentially ambiguous depending on the data sent.  It is unlikely given the length and format of the delimiters, but it's something to keep in mind if there ever exists the possibility of having actual data that "looks" like a delimiter.

Assuming that the example shown is one of many similar protocols, I would be inclined to go a different route.  One possibility would be to bundle up the request as a **JSON object**.  There are existing packages available to create and read JSON.  One example is [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx).  JSON has a well-defined structure, it is easy for a human to read and verify, and it can be expanded easily. And depending on the data that you send, it would probably a little more lightweight than the current format. And (maybe the part you are interested in), it would maybe seem more "professional".

A couple of additional things that I would do (personal opinion):

- Possibly add a client version to the data being sent so the server will know if it "recognizes" the request.  Start the client version at some value (e.g., 1).  If there are updates to the protocol format (e.g., different data, different structure), change the version to 2 in that release of the software.  Then the server can look at the version number to see if it recognizes it.  If it is the first version of the server and sees version 2, then it can return an error indicating the server needs to be updated.  This is not necessary if you can guarantee that the client and server releases are always matched (sometimes this is hard in practice).
- Use an integer value for the request type instead of a string ('checkFileMD5'). If there are going to be a large number of request types, the server can dispatch the request a little more efficiently (maybe) based on an integer value.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, could you perhaps elaborate on `"Possibly a client version to the data being sent"` because I do not understand that sentence. JSON is looking pretty good so far.

Comment: @natli:  Sorry about that; it didn't help that I left a word out of the sentence.  I edited and added clarifying information.

Comment: Ah, makes sense now! Thanks alot, looks like I have some work to do ;)